# How to change react redux states in realtime for a database change?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-redux

In my react app, I'm accessing a postgres db through a backend API, and updating a table in frontend. But the data in the database can be changed. Based on the change I need to update the frontend Table as well. So here, what is the correct way to get those change from db?

Actually i'm looking for a correct way of Long polling between the react app and the back-end.

Comment: could you provide an example of what you are trying to do? "changed" is a bit broad.

Comment: edited above question